# How to pass string to argument within factor function in r glm?

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to use for loop to run a glm model with different lag values (i.e. from 1 to 21),

I used the following code to run:

```
modelcpr1 = vector(mode = 'list', length = 21L)

for(i in 1:21){

modelcpr1[[i]] = hhh %>% 
  
               glm(n ~ PM2.5 +
                                                               
                       factor(sym(paste('min_lag_',i,'_yearly',sep = '')),levels = c('4','1','2','3','5')),
                   
                   data =., family=poisson
                   
                  ) 

}
```

However,
the following error popped up:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = n ~ PM2.5  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'factor(sym(paste("min_lag_", i, "_yearly", sep = "")), levels = c("4", "1", "2", "3", "5"))')
```

Is there any way to convert strings into an argument within `factor` function?